# Why is UseState in ReactJS preventing a boolean from updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

so I have a code that is desgined to rearrange a list of users printed on a table by name. When I just simply console.log() the arranged array it works perfectly. As soon as I introduce useState it updates just once.

so here is the original working code

```
 import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'


export const Table = () => {

 
 // ///////////////////UseState Array //
 let asc = true
 var newArr
 const [Array2,SetArray] = useState([
     {rank:1,name:'Sam', age:25, gender:true},
     {rank:2,name:'Bill', age:35, gender:true},
     {rank:3,name:'John', age:22, gender:true},
     {rank:4,name:'Sarah', age:19, gender:false}]
 )
 const Alpha2 = ()=>{
    console.log(asc)


if (asc===true){
     newArr = [...Array2].sort((a,b) => (a.name> b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0))
    asc = false 

    console.log('cond 1')
  
    }
   
else if(asc=== false ){
     newArr = [...Array2].sort((a,b) => (b.name> a.name) ? 1 : ((a.name > b.name) ? -1 : 0))
     asc = true 
     console.log('cond 2')
    
}
console.log(newArr)



}


//                  
    return (
        <div className="Table">
              
            </div>
             <h3>Table 2</h3>
             <div className="Standings">
<div className="column">
                <div> <h3>Rank</h3></div>
               <div onClick= {()=>Alpha2()}> <h3 >Name</h3></div>
                <div> <h3 onClick= {()=>Numa()}>Age</h3></div>
                <div> <h3>Gender</h3></div>
</div>
            {Array2.map((profile)=>(
            <div key={profile.rank} className="column">
                 <div> <h3>{profile.rank}</h3></div>
                <div> <h3>{profile.name}</h3></div>
                <div> <h3>{profile.age}</h3></div>
                <div> <h3>{profile.gender?'male': 'female'}</h3></div>
                 
                                          
            </div>
        
     ))}

             </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Table
```

it console logs the arranged array after an odd number of clicks as

```
: {rank: 2, name: 'Bill', age: 35, gender: true}
1: {rank: 3, name: 'John', age: 22, gender: true}
2: {rank: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 25, gender: true}
3: {rank: 4, name: 'Sarah', age: 19, gender: false}
```

and after an even number of clicks as

```
0: {rank: 4, name: 'Sarah', age: 19, gender: false}
1: {rank: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 25, gender: true}
2: {rank: 3, name: 'John', age: 22, gender: true}
3: {rank: 2, name: 'Bill', age: 35, gender: true}
```

Which is what I want since it is rearranging alphabetically every time (once in descending and the other time in ascending orders). The asc variable keeps rotating between true and false.

but when I use the useState function SetArray by modifying Alpha2 function like this

```
 const Alpha2 = ()=>{
    console.log(asc)


if (asc===true){
     newArr = [...Array2].sort((a,b) => (a.name> b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0))
    asc = false 

    console.log('cond 1')
  
    }
   
else if(asc=== false ){
     newArr = [...Array2].sort((a,b) => (b.name> a.name) ? 1 : ((a.name > b.name) ? -1 : 0))
     asc = true 
     console.log('cond 2')
    
}
SetArray(newArr)

console.log(newArr)



}
```

It only changes the array once into

```
rank: 2, name: 'Bill', age: 35, gender: true}
1: {rank: 3, name: 'John', age: 22, gender: true}
2: {rank: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 25, gender: true}
3: {rank: 4, name: 'Sarah', age: 19, gender: false}
```

but it stays the same afterwards as the asc variable never changes from false back to true like it would in the earlier version of the function

so what is going on? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated, but consistent, reasonable code formatting makes code a lot easier to reason about. This is like ~90 lines of which 1/3 are blank, and flow/logic is hidden by random indentation.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had to delete out other functions that were not part of the question so I did not re-edit properly after the deletions and left a lot of spaces blank.

Comment: In any case, `asc` isn't a variable that will cause a re-render, because it's not a state or property reference. I can't quite read the code, but it's likely you want an effect on `asc` which updates `Array2`. (Also unrelated, but I'd stick w/ normal JS naming conventions to keep things more clear.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is that useState re-renders the page while simply changing the variable 'asc' from true to false does not.

Essentially, whenever you call useState it refreshes the page and in doing so resets any hard coded variable back to its original value.

The only way to change this is to use a hook for the 'asc' variable  like this

```
 const [asc, setAsc] = useState(true)
```

and then change it with

```
setAsc(false)
```

That should fix it.